# Get user input typed in adaptive card c# and reply with details

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework

I have created an adaptive card for my bot to pass to users if it can't find anything they are looking for.

The thing is i'm not sure how to get the Submit button in the adaptive card to collect information. At some point i want to get it to send an email but for now i just need to figure out how to collect the user input and display that input back to them

Here is the code i have i c#

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, I couldn't find what your looking for."), cancellationToken);
      if (turnContext.Activity.Text != ("Sorry, I couldn't find what your looking for."))
      {
        var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(File.ReadAllText("CaseAdaptivecard.json")).Card }); //pass adaptive card to content
```

here is the adaptive card Json file

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "size": "stretch",
            "horizontalAlignment": "center"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 2,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Details of issues",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "size": "Medium"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Please let me know the issues your having and i'll pass this to my creators :)",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Container",
                            "$data": "${properties}",
                            "items": [
                               
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                    "id": "Email.Block",
                                    "label": "Email"
                                },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "Subject.Block",
                                        "label": "Subject"
                                    }
                                
                                
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "id": "Description.Block",
            "label": "Description"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit",
            "data": {
                "prop1": true,
                "prop2": []}
        }
    
    ]
}
```

Comment: _"Action.Submit .. **gathers input fields**, merges with optional data field, and sends an event to the client"_ - https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html

Comment: what is the channel type? webchat or ms team, etc?

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks submit, that sends an actvity back to the bot. Simply, it might look something like:

```json
{
  "channelData": {
  },
  "type": "message",
  "value": {
    "prop1": true,
    "prop2": [],
    "Email.Block": "email",
    "Subject.Block": "sub",
    "Description.Block": "desc"
  },
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "name": "User",
  },
  "recipient": {
    "name": "Bot",
  }
}
```

This does not have the typical 'text' value that would exist a normal message to the bot like this:

```json
{
  "channelData": {
  },
  "text": "Hello there bot!",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "type": "message",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "name": "User",
  },
  "recipient": {
    "name": "Bot",
  }
}
```

But you can see that it does have the submitted values back in the 'value' property.

These are both of type `message`, so you just need to handle checking for those properties (`turnContext.Activity.Value`) in your [OnMessageActivityAsync](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/648a181d96184ca84204b1d82fa7ecfddc5adb19/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards/Bots/AdaptiveCardsBot.cs#L45) handler.